# Find the correct CSS-selector for last child to add Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm having trouble finding the correct CSS selector.
I need a jQuery that detects that the focus leaves the last child of the submenu (.blur).
I tried some stuff like:

```
$('.responsive-nav > ul > li:last-child').blur(function (e) {
```

But I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong here.
Below you can find the Html in plain code and in a Js Fiddle if needed.

**What is the correct css selector for this case?** And is there some good documentation about css selectors that I can learn it better myself?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<nav id="topNav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="responsive-nav">
            <div class="responsiveModus"></div>
            <!--BeginNoIndex-->
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="Item01 level1">
                    <div tabindex="1" class="box">
                        <a href="#" title="Mainpage1"><span>Mainpage1</span></a>
                        <div class="subNav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage1"><span>Subpage1</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage2"><span>Subpage2</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage3"><span>Subpage3</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage4"><span>Subpage4</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage5"><span>Subpage5</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage6"><span>Subpage6</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage7"><span>Subpage7</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="Item02 level1">
                    <div class="box">
                        <a href="#" title="Mainpage2"><span>Mainpage2</span></a>
                        <div class="subNav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage1"><span>Subpage1</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage2"><span>Subpage2</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage3"><span>Subpage3</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage4"><span>Subpage4</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" title="Subpage5"><span>Subpage5</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--EndNoIndex-->
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HwD3j/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider is it working? http://jsfiddle.net/HwD3j/1/ as you want

Comment: or this as you want to select? http://jsfiddle.net/HwD3j/2/

Comment: @C-link No, it should select the last link of submenu -> not sure how to select this

Comment: @C-link The second is the one I need thanks! Can you explain the use of .responsive-nav > ul > li li:last-child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select using like this:

```
$('.responsive-nav > ul > li li:last-child').css('background','red');
```

[see more for css selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

```
E > F   Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

E F Matches any F element that is a descendant of an E element.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Its becoming more clear to me now. +1

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work `$(".subNav>ul>li:last-child")`